# Making a subdirectory independent using the .htaccess file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, web, subdirectory

Let's say that I have a subdirectory in my `www` folder called `subdirectory`. Is it possible to modify the `.htaccess` file so that all files contained within the subdirectory can be referenced inside other files like this: `/somefile.extension`? Therefore, I'd like the subdirectory to act as the root for all files inside it, and I don't want to use a subdomain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://site.com/subdirectory/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subdirectory/
RewriteRule (.*) /subdirectory/$1 [L,QSA]
```